# android thread manager: dynamically change task order

Tags: android

in my app, I want to implement an image viewer. The viewer needs to download a large amount of images from my own server using urls. 
   I want to do this in background (not block the UI).
   But the tricky part is I need to dynamically change the order of the downloading task by the main activity. For example, there are 3 tasks right now, and the user click a button in the main activity, then the app needs to add a new task, but also the new coming task need to be execute first (with highest priority)?
   How should I do this?

thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Lucklily you csn't do any mess like you wanted on system level. Use `IntentService` with task queue and manage your background jobs there